# Why is a Map in Java not a Collection?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Intuitive, I would say a Map/Dictionary, ect. is a Collection. Why is a Map (Interface) in Java not an extension (extends) of the Collection (Interface).

Comment: Map and dictionary are collections (small c), as they are part of the collections framework; they just don't implement `Collection` because they require different methods to things like `List`. Perhaps that is a failing in the choice of "Collection" as the interface name.

Comment: Collection has been given a specific meaning of a collection of elements, it doesn't apply to any collection as we might describe it in English.  A Map is a collection of values associated with a key.

Answer (score 0):

A `Map` doesn't have some of the methods of the `Collection` interface (such as `add`, `contains`, etc...), so it can't extend that interface.

A `Collection` represents a group of elements of a single common type. A `Map` does not - it represents a mapping of elements of one type (called keys) to elements of another type (called values).